# Код проверяет только однозначные цифры и не выходит из цикла. Как сделать, чтобы проверял и многозначные, и как выходить из цикла после этого?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Пояснение: сейчас `simvol_alp = msg in n1` проверяет только 1 символ от ввода пользователя, если ввести два или более, то это уже не учитывается. Как можно сделать, чтобы учитывались и многозначные числа?

И как после ввода пользователем ставки выйти из этого цикла?

```
    n1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]
    if msg == "монетка":
        otmena = VkKeyboard(one_time=True)
        otmena.add_button("Отмена")
        send_some_msg(id, "Введите сумму ставки!", otmena)          
        for event in longpoll.listen():                 
            if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                if event.to_me and event.text:
                    msg = event.text.lower()
                    simvol_alp = msg in n1
                    if simvol_alp == True:
                        send_some_msg(id, "Ставка Принята!")
                    else:
                        send_some_msg(id, "Ставка НЕ Принята!")
```

Comment: и еще хотел спросить как после ввода пользователем ставки выйти из этого цикла

Comment: Вы бы код взяли и проанализировали. А взять чужой код и задать непонятный вопрос - мало толку. Откуда мы знаем, на что вы проверять собираетесь? Но коротко: 1) модифицируйте `n1` для проверки.  2) Выход - через `break` попробуйте.

Comment: Это мой код а не чужой, но спасибо

Comment: Как же он может быть вашим, если вы сделали проверку на однозначные цифры, но не знаете, как сделать на многозначные? И сам код относительно сложный, а вопросы выглядят элементарными.

Comment: Я задавал вопрос по поводу системы ставок просто я изучал каждый элемент строки а мне подсказали что можно проверить именно саму строку на предмет нахождения а этот код который мне подсказали `simvol_alp = msg in n1` проверяет только 1 символ от вода пользователя если ввести два или более то это уже не учитывается , вот я и хотел спросить как можно сделать чтобы учитывались и многозначные числа

Comment: эта строка проверяет наличие msg  в списке n1, а не "только 1 символ от вода пользователя". Если бы умели хотя бы основы питона, то смогли бы легко дополнить этот код до нужного.  К тому же, так и осталось непонятным, что вам вообще требуется проверить. Текущая формулировка оставляет простор для разных интерпретаций.

Comment: Тогда ставьте вопросы правильно. Изучите, как я изменил ваш вопрос (заголовок и поле текста).

Comment: А две строчки ``simvol_alp = msg in n1`` и ``if simvol_alp == True:`` сокращаются до одной ``if msg in n1``.

Comment: Спасибо Большое – 
Roman-Stop RU aggression in UA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для проверки, что строка состоит из цифр используйте `isnumeric`, для выхода из цикла - `break`:

```
for event in longpoll.listen():                 
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
         if event.to_me and event.text:
             msg = event.text.lower()
             if msg.isnumeric():
                 send_some_msg(id, "Ставка Принята!")
                 break
             else:
                 send_some_msg(id, "Ставка НЕ Принята!")
```